# Regular Expression that finds out the location inside the C Folder

Tags: regex, batch-file

I need a regular expression that finds out the batch file inside the C Folder, Here is the regular expression with the internal folders inside C folder :

Regular Expression : C:\(.*?).bat

Location : c:\Pangaea\7709\TestExecutables\BIOS\update.bat

But my requirement is it needs to find only inside C Folder : c:\update.bat

Could any one give me the expression to find ???

Comment: At least one tag specifying the environment the RegEx operates in, is missing. And as `[batch-file]` has normally no RegEx capabilities (aside from Findstr's rudimentary ones) but wildcards this tag is disputable.

Answer (score 0):

You can just look for all string that do not include the `\`

Like:

```
C:\\([^\\]*).bat
```

see: https://regex101.com/r/LB2TXC/1

You need to escape the `\` in most languages

Comment: Yeah I Had Given Long Bak :)